# VisualStudio running two different sets of tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Currently I have a (hobby) project containing about 3,800 tests. From these tests, about 3,000 take quite some time (in total 5 minutes).

Since I'm going to refactor a lot in the next months, I need to run it very often, and it would be nice to have them split in two groups, one (those 3,000) which are more like integration tests, and one group of unit tests which (partly sadly) test some functionality.

Is it possible to make multiple groups and run each group separately? Or should I pack them in a different test project?

(Btw, I'm aware that it would be better to have mostly unit tests, but those 3,000 'slow' tests where very fast to make and since I have sparse free time, I took the disadvantage into account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much exactly the same situation I'm in. As you have mentioned, it is unfortunate that the tests suite has grown this way over the cause of the project. We have around 6000 tests and around 4000 are Integration Tests. The rest (~2000) mainly Unit Tests.

When I joined the project one of the first thing I did was to completely decouple Unit tests and Integration Tests. Basically pack them into different projects. One ends up *UnitTests.csproj and the other IntegrationTests.csproj
Side note: From that on wards I encourage everyone to write more Unit tests (than Integration tests), but that did not exactly work the way I expected :)

Any way...
Unit tests:
Decoupling tests project was the key because now we could run Unit tests separately to integration tests. You can configure them to run part of CI builds and they will run quickly.

In you case you can even look at removing lot of integration tests (during refactor), and write Unit tests to get much more value out of your tests suite.

Integration tests - has so much functionality being tested and so many slow tests. We cannot afford to run them part of the CI builds - too slow. Therefore we run them in a scheduled build every couple of hours or so. If one of the test has failed, priority is to fix the failing test asap.We just cannot get rid of these tests as it shows the stability of the current even not done in the right way.

Comment: Thanks, in that way I'm going for two projects. My tests are already reasonably split. Actually, the about 4,000 integration tests are generated more or less automatically, it's like loading a file and performing a set of basic operations. All 4,000 files are different.

And as soon as my unit test are a bit more code-coveraged, I can easily run them offline (it's a hobby project anyway so I have lots of gaps in between developing, every week a 1-5 hours split over the week). However, for refactoring a bunch of very fast unit tests would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the tests into two projects, or use a custom attribute. See [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.6.3) for details

In essence, mark slow running tests:

```
namespace NUnit.Tests
{
  using System;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [TestFixture]
  [Category("LongRunning")]
  public class LongRunningTests
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and then you can use  `/include` and `/exclude` arguments to run what you want from a prompt.
e.g.

```
nunit-console myassembly.dll /exclude:LongRunning
```

Comment: Thanks I like the way of the attributes, but not so much a command line action. But the attribute itself seems like a good way.

Comment: You can use the attributes in a GUI if you prefer.